# How can I restrict windows 7 to only use the local subnet, but block the internet

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, firewall, home-networking

I want to block all internet connections to and from my windows 7 machine, but allow it to access everything on the local network. The local network is behind an Apple Airport Extreme.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to do this on a permanent basis, or based on some condition?

Comment: I'd like a way to do this by script, but it does not have to respond to anything from the outside.

Comment: I amended my answer and added control by script.

Answer (score 13):

## Option #1 (Windows Firewall rules)

You could create a firewall rule to block these connections. Follow these steps:

#### Change the default firewall behavior to block outbound network connections:

1. Enter "firewall" from the Start search and open "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security".
2. Notice which firewall profile is active. It says "... is active" in the overview list.
3. Click on `Windows Firewall Properties`
4. Change state for Outbound connections **for the active profile** to `Block`.
5. Click OK to apply.

#### Create a firewall rule to allow local network outbound connections:

2. Go to `Outbound Rules` and select `New Rule...` from the Actions in the right pane.
3. Rule type should be `Custom`:
4. Go to the `Scope` step and for the **remote** IP address, select `these IP addresses`, then `Add..`, then `Predefined set of computers` and finally `Local Subnet`.
5. Go to `Name` step, enter name of "Allow local Subnet" and click Finish.

You're done configuring it!

### Control via script

To block all outbound Internet traffic:

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile firewallpolicy blockinbound,blockoutbound
```

To allow all outbound Internet traffic

```
netsh advfirewall set currentprofile firewallpolicy blockinbound,allowoutbound
```

## Option #2 (Specialized software)

If you are trying to block Internet access as a result of excessive Internet usage, there is specialized software that can block all Internet access when monthly or daily Internet traffic exceeds pre-defined maximum. Local network access is still allowed, though.
One such program is [DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about), which also has many other bells and whistles related to Internet bandwidth management on Windows computer.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of DU Meter.

Comment: Does this work on win8?

Comment: Should work, I haven't tested, though.

Comment: @Jairo Jamyang Pawo Moreno: If you suggest an edit and it is rejected (by a unanimous vote!), please do not resubmit (essentially) the exact same edit.  If you believe that you have a better way to do it, post a separate answer.  If you believe that the answer is currently wrong, post a comment explaining why.  [Yeah, I know that you don’t have the privilege to comment yet.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/271976 "Why do I need 50 reputation to comment?   What can I do instead?")

Answer (score 10):

If you disable DHCP then set an IP address and subnet mask but leave default gateway blank, then your computer will be unable to access outside the local network.

If someone is an administrator over the local machine, they would be able to reverse this if they were trying, but if that isn't a concern then this should work.

Comment: +1: Make sure that the IP address you pick isn't part of the DHCP scope.

Comment: This is brilliant! LAN works and no internet at all. I put my router IP DNS in so that I can still use LAN DNS names for devices. SO simple! Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

If you're working through the GUI in Windows 8.x:

1. set the Scope of the Local IP address to "Any IP address"
2. set the Remote IP address to "These IP addresses"
3. select "Internet" under the list of "Predefined set of computers"

   Make sure to check the correct profile that is assigned to the network card that you want this rule to work on. Lastly:
4. check that the rule is enabled
5. set the Action to "Block the connection"

   The rule is active immediately