# Allow dropbox through windows firewall when everything else is blocked

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, dropbox, windows-firewall

Using [this solution](https://superuser.com/a/345866/301932) I've blocked all internet access with windows firewall and made an exception to allow local subnet traffic through the firewall.

How would I allow dropbox through the firewall as well? Adding an exception for both inbound and outbound allowing the application dropbox.exe through didn't work.

I've also allowed dns through the firewall but it still doesn't let dropbox sync right. It just says "connecting" on the dropbox status.

Answer (score 1):

You have to type the complete folder path to dropbox.exe in the exception rule in the windows firewall, do not use %appdata%.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox should be fine with app perms and DNS, as you've described.  Check that you have the rules applied to the network profile (Home/Work || Public) you're actually using.

Simple way:

Start->search "allow a program through..." -> dropbox

Check both boxes.

Comment: Yeah, the right profiles are set for those rules. And DNS works since I can ping it.

    
I can't ping dropbox.com but I assume that's because I didn't let dropbox's ip through, only the application. But the application still hangs on "connecting".

Are there any services or other processes that I need to let through other than "%APPDATA%\Dropbox\bin\Dropbox.exe"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from reading the other answer and your comment to it, that you have problems finding out which processes to whitelist so dropbox can connect.

try this:

1. disable the windows firewall completely
2. press windowskey+r and then type in "cmd" (without quotes) and hit enter
3. in the new window, type "netstat -b"
   -you should now see a list of programs which are currently connected or have open listening ports.
4. open dropbox and connect
5. type "netstat -b" again in the command line window

you are now able to compare which programs are connected to the internet with dropbox on and dropbox off by scrolling up and down in the window. if you see programs which appear only on the second output, you have found the programs you need whitelist in the firewall.