# How to disable win8's internet access even after reboot?

Tags: windows-8

I am using [SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com/index.html) on Mac, this app could disable the whole internet even when you reboot the system. So I am wondering if this is possible with Windows.

How can I block  a win8 computer's access to internet(I mean, the whole internet) even when you reboot the computer? Do you have to edit your `hosts` or something?

Comment: Windows has `Parental Controls` builtin you can use.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the last resort, because that's so shameful.

Comment: How is it shameful exactly

Comment: @Ramhound You need another guy to set a password to get the parent control work, unlike Self-Control, you can be your own master.

Answer (score 1):

This link references Windows 7, but it should work for Windows 8 as well:
[How can I restrict windows 7 to only use the local subnet, but block the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/345758/how-can-i-restrict-windows-7-to-only-use-the-local-subnet-but-block-the-interne)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [SelfRestraint](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Other-Internet-Related/SelfRestraint.shtml) - I believe it is similar to that app and it is created for Windows OS.

Comment: Does it work even after you reboot, Sir?